# Listen to a queue in a controller Spring MVC and Spring web socket

Tags: java, spring-mvc, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I have a scenario where we have an application that uses Spring MVC and spring web-socket. I want to write a method in a controller that listens to messages and then once it gets that message it will transform and send it to another queue that the user listens on the client side.

The client side code looks like

```
    var connect = function() {
    var socket = new SockJS(webSocketUrl);
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {

        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe("/user/queue/test", function(data){ 
            alert(data);               
    }
    }
    );
```

I am not sure how the java code should look like

```
@SubscribeMapping("/queue/cluwe.controller.sign") 
public void signMessagesAggregator() {
    String blah = "test";
    simpMessageSendingOperations.convertAndSendToUser("userId", "/queue/test", blah);
}
```

I know the java part is wrong, but I cant find any documentation in spring-websockets that have a stompClient.subscribe like thing in java. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like that:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/events")
    //subscribed to /hello and sends Greeting to /topic/events
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

}
```

Application should be configured with @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker and broker need to be configured. Have a look at a [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Answer (score 0):

Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Sending a message

```
@Autowired
SimpMessagingTemplate template;
//all users
template.convertAndSend("/topic/mytopic/", "message")
//especific user
template.convertAndSendToUser("userId", "/topic/mytopic/", "message"));
```

client side

```
  stomp.connect('/websocket', {})
    .then(function() {
      stomp.subscribe('/topic/mytopic/', function(message) {
        console.log('message' + message)
      });
    });
```